# Android: Howto get a resource id of an android resource

Tags: android, resources

I want to get a resource id of an android resource that I have saved in /res/raw folder.

The use -

1) I am passing the name of the resource to the class and this name is being saved in a string fileNeme.

2) The statement for getting this file is `this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xyz)` where xyz is the actual filename.

3) I understand that openRawResource(int) method takes an int value hence I cannot use the statement as `this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)` where filename is a string variable defined above.

Problem: I know the filename which is saved in a string called filename but I cannot open it as the method takes the resource id in int format.

I need to get the resource id of this filename and save it in an int variable filename_int and pass this variable to openRawResource method.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should be able to get the resource id with `getIdentifier()` :

```
int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("xyz", "raw", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: thank you! To save the next guy some time the "xyz" parameter is exactly the chars you want for your xml file. Besure you got nothing before or after it. No "res/" or "@raw" etc.. just clean xyz

Comment: Also, the "xyz" should not include any suffix. e.g. raw resource myfile.json would just be "myfile".

Comment: @silver_man Bingo! That's the comment that fixed my issue :-)

Comment: For drawables `this.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_spellcheck_white_24dp", "drawable", this.getPackageName());`