# How to dynamically reference an XML id to play a sound

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a soundboard, such that when you press a button with a particular android:id it will play an .ogg file of the same name. I have the layout setup, just need assistance with referencing the XML id.

For instance, if I have this particular button setup

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/file022"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:onClick="playSound"
            android:background="#B3EDEDED"/>
```

I could use the following code to play back the corresponding sound to play file022.ogg

```
(v.getId()==R.id.button14){
        MediaPlayer mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file022);
        mpSound.start();
```

What do I need to change such that I can avoid hardcoding case statements for 'R.raw.file001', 'R.raw.file002', and instead dynamically reference the id as set in the XML?

Comment: You can create custom button`SoundButton` which will have attribute `sound` (refer to you file from raw) and after re-use it at your code. See [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this using instead the `tag` attribute, as retrieving the field name for the ID would require reflection.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:tag="file022"
    ... />
```

Then, in your code, you just retrieve the tag, and get the raw resource identifier for that name.

```
String tag = (String) v.getTag();
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(tag, "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
mpSound.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your button, you can give it a `tag` to identify the sound resource to play

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/file022" 
    ... contents skipped for brevity
    android:tag="file022" <--- add a tag which maps to your sound resource name
    />
```

Then assign a `View.OnClickListener` to the button in your `Activity` (or `Fragment`).

For the implementation of `onClick(View)`, you can do something similar to this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    int soundResourceId = [yourContextObject].getResources().getIdentifier(v.getTag(), "raw", this.getPackageName());
    // play the sound
    MediaPlayer mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundResourceId );
    // etc...
}
```

Note: this assumes that the tag is set and the `OnClickListener` is only assigned to buttons that play the sound. Also, i used a placeholder `[yourContextObject]`, so you can use `YourActivity.this` or if its in a `Fragment` `getContext()` so you can access the app resources

This might be a little tedious to maintain if you change your resource names though since you would have to change the value of the `android:tag` attribute in your view.

Credit to this StackOverflow thread for the string to resource conversion: [Android: Howto get a resource id of an android resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921121/android-howto-get-a-resource-id-of-an-android-resource)

Note: `Resources.getResource(...)` might be a bit slow, instead you can store the R file resource references in a static final array in your class and create a mapping between the array and your buttons by storing an index instead of the file name in the `android:tag`, and just use: `int soundResourceId = yourResourceArray[Integer.parseInt(v.getTag())]` to get the index for the array

EDIT: another alternative if you wanna stick with the tag == file name is to use something like this:
[Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Comment: Thanks for your response! That definitely helps with my core objective of this exercise; learning about android app development